# Map child object with condition using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two domain classes, pair and run, as well as their Dto representations.

I'm trying to set one of the values inside the `runDto` such as `RunEt` dependant on the `PairFinish` value inside the `qualifyingDto`.

I have tried using `forMember()`, `AfterMap()` and `ForPath()`, but they don't seem to work. Do I have to use a value resolver or am I missing something?

**Pair**

```
public partial class Pair
{
    public Pair()
    {
        PairDetails = new HashSet<PairDetail>();
        Runs = new HashSet<Run>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime PairTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long PairEvent { get; set; }
    public string PairMode { get; set; }
    public short? PairRound { get; set; }
    public short PairFinish { get; set; }
    public long PairCateg { get; set; }

    public virtual Categ PairCategNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Event PairEventNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PairDetail> PairDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Run> Runs { get; set; }
}
```

**Run**

```
public partial class Run
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime RunTimestamp { get; set; }
        public short RunLane { get; set; }
        public string RunRacenum { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunIndex { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunRt { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt60 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt330 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt594 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt660 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunSp660 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt934 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt1000 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunSp1000 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt1254 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunEt1320 { get; set; }
        public decimal? RunSp1320 { get; set; }
        public string RunStartRemarks { get; set; }
        public string RunFinishRemarks { get; set; }
        public string RunDq { get; set; }

        public virtual Pair RunTimestampNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual RunDetail RunDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

**PairDto**

```
public class QualifyingPairDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime PairTimestamp { get; set; }
    public QualifyingRunDto LeftLane { get; set; }
    public QualifyingRunDto RightLane { get; set; }
    public short PairFinish { get; set; }
}
```

**RunDto**

```
public class QualifyingRunDto

{
    public long Id { get; set;  }
    public DateTime RunTimestamp { get; set; }
    public short RunLane { get; set; }
    public string RunRacenum { get; set; }
    public decimal? RunIndex { get; set; }
    public decimal? RunRt { get; set; }
    public decimal? RunEt { get; set; }
    public decimal? RunSp { get; set; }
    public string RunStartRemarks { get; set; }
    public string RunFinishRemarks { get; set; }
    public string RunDq { get; set; }
    public short Finish { get; set; }
}
```

Initially, I tried doing this using `forMemember()`, however, this throws an error.

```
.ForMember(d => d.LeftLane.RunEt, o => o.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
        {
            switch (src.PairFinish)
            {
                case 1:
                    return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1320;
                case 2:
                    return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1000;
                case 3:
                    return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt660;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }));
```

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression 'd => d.LeftLane.RunEt' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.'

So then I tried using `ForPath` and `AfterMap` (separately) which both would leave the `RunDto.RunEt` as null.

```
.ForPath(d => d.LeftLane.RunEt, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 2).First().RunEt1320));

.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            switch (src.PairFinish)
            {
                case 1:
                    dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1320;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1000;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt660;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

**This is my complete mapping profile**

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Event, Event>();
        CreateMap<EventMaster, EventMaster>();
        CreateMap<Track, Track>();

        CreateMap<Event, EventDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.EventEm.Name))
            .ForMember(d => d.Track, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.EventEm.Track));

        CreateMap<Run, QualifyingRunDto>();

        CreateMap<Pair, QualifyingPairDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.LeftLane, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First()))
            .ForMember(d => d.RightLane, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 2).First()))


        //.ForPath(d => d.LeftLane.RunEt, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 2).First().RunEt1320));

        //.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        //{
        //    switch (src.PairFinish)
        //    {
        //        case 1:
        //            dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1320;
        //            break;
        //        case 2:
        //            dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1000;
        //            break;
        //        case 3:
        //            dest.LeftLane.RunEt = src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt660;
        //            break;
        //        default:
        //            break;
        //    }
        //});

        //.ForMember(d => d.LeftLane.RunEt, o => o.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
        //{
        //    switch (src.PairFinish)
        //    {
        //        case 1:
        //            return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1320;
        //        case 2:
        //            return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt1000;
        //        case 3:
        //            return src.Runs.Where(r => r.RunLane == 1).First().RunEt660;
        //        default:
        //            break;
        //    }
        //    return null;
        //}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it the "correct" way to do this, but I think your `AfterMap` should work. What value have you set for `Pair.PairFinish` while testing? The only way I can see `RunDto.FinishEt` being `null` is if the case if falling through to the default. Have you stepped through it?

Comment: Pair.PairFinish has a value of 3

Comment: Looking at it again. `FinishEt` is never mapped. That is why it is `null`.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo on my part, runEt is meant to be finishEt. I  have corrected the post